# How to make an effect "Overlay" on the rest of the page when the menu is displayed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a navigation bar that displays a "Callapse" menu.
The menu appears from the right to the right with a transition of 0.5s
I added an "Overlay" effect to the rest of the screen when the menu is displayed.

I want this "Overlay" effect to appear with a 0.5s transition from right to left to join my menu.

How to do this ?

```
#navbar-collapse {
    z-index: 1031;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100% !important;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#navbar-collapse::after {
    z-index: 1029;
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    left: 250px;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Voici les modèles de ma page Drupal 8 :

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a single page.
 *
 * The doctype, html, head and body tags are not in this template. Instead they
 * can be found in the html.html.twig template in this directory.
 *
 * Available variables:
 *
 * General utility variables:
 * - base_path: The base URL path of the Drupal installation. Will usually be
 *   "/" unless you have installed Drupal in a sub-directory.
 * - is_front: A flag indicating if the current page is the front page.
 * - logged_in: A flag indicating if the user is registered and signed in.
 * - is_admin: A flag indicating if the user has permission to access
 *   administration pages.
 *
 * Site identity:
 * - front_page: The URL of the front page. Use this instead of base_path when
 *   linking to the front page. This includes the language domain or prefix.
 *
 * Navigation:
 * - breadcrumb: The breadcrumb trail for the current page.
 *
 * Page content (in order of occurrence in the default page.html.twig):
 * - title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed in front of the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - title: The page title, for use in the actual content.
 * - title_suffix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed after the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - messages: Status and error messages. Should be displayed prominently.
 * - tabs: Tabs linking to any sub-pages beneath the current page (e.g., the
 *   view and edit tabs when displaying a node).
 * - action_links: Actions local to the page, such as "Add menu" on the menu
 *   administration interface.
 * - node: Fully loaded node, if there is an automatically-loaded node
 *   associated with the page and the node ID is the second argument in the
 *   page's path (e.g. node/12345 and node/12345/revisions, but not
 *   comment/reply/12345).
 *
 * Regions:
 * - page.header: Items for the header region.
 * - page.navigation: Items for the navigation region.
 * - page.navigation_collapsible: Items for the navigation (collapsible) region.
 * - page.highlighted: Items for the highlighted content region.
 * - page.help: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages.
 * - page.content: The main content of the current page.
 * - page.sidebar_first: Items for the first sidebar.
 * - page.sidebar_second: Items for the second sidebar.
 * - page.footer: Items for the footer region.
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_page()
 * @see html.html.twig
 */
#}
{% set container = theme.settings.fluid_container ? 'container-fluid' : 'container' %}
{# Navigation (collapsible) #}
{% if page.navigation_collapsible %}
  <div id="navbar-collapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse width">
    {{ page.navigation_collapsible }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
{# Navbar #}
{% if page.navigation or page.navigation_collapsible %}
  {% block navbar %}
    {%
      set navbar_classes = [
        'navbar',
        theme.settings.navbar_inverse ? 'navbar-inverse' : 'navbar-default',
        theme.settings.navbar_position ? 'navbar-' ~ theme.settings.navbar_position|clean_class : container,
      ]
    %}
    <header{{ navbar_attributes.addClass(navbar_classes) }} id="navbar" role="banner">
      {% if not navbar_attributes.hasClass(container) %}
        <div class="{{ container }}">
      {% endif %}
      <div class="navbar-header">
        {{ page.navigation }}
        {# .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content #}
      </div>

      {% if not navbar_attributes.hasClass(container) %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </header>
  {% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{# Main #}
{% block main %}
  <div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">
    <div class="row">

      {# Header #}
      {% if page.header %}
        {% block header %}
          <div class="col-sm-12" role="heading">
            {{ page.header }}
          </div>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}

      {# Sidebar First #}
      {% if page.sidebar_first %}
        {% block sidebar_first %}
          <aside class="col-sm-3" role="complementary">
            {{ page.sidebar_first }}
          </aside>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}

      {# Content #}
      {%
        set content_classes = [
          page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second ? 'col-sm-6',
          page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-md-9',
          page.sidebar_second and page.sidebar_first is empty ? 'col-md-9',
          page.sidebar_first is empty and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-sm-12'
        ]
      %}
      <section{{ content_attributes.addClass(content_classes) }}>

        {# Highlighted #}
        {% if page.highlighted %}
          {% block highlighted %}
            <div class="highlighted">{{ page.highlighted }}</div>
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Breadcrumbs #}
        {% if breadcrumb %}
          {% block breadcrumb %}
            {{ breadcrumb }}
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Action Links #}
        {% if action_links %}
          {% block action_links %}
            <ul class="action-links">{{ action_links }}</ul>
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Help #}
        {% if page.help %}
          {% block help %}
            {{ page.help }}
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Content #}
        {% block content %}
          <a id="main-content"></a>
          {{ page.content }}
        {% endblock %}
      </section>

      {# Sidebar Second #}
      {% if page.sidebar_second %}
        {% block sidebar_second %}
          <aside class="col-md-3" role="complementary">
            {{ page.sidebar_second }}
          </aside>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% if page.footer %}
  {% block footer %}
    <footer class="footer {{ container }}" role="contentinfo">
      {{ page.footer }}
    </footer>
  {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: A transition happens when something _changes_, right? So start it off differently than the end result. Also btw, this question isn't a good fit for SO. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can just increase the `width` from 0% to 100% which will make it appear like it's sliding in. Also position the pseudo element to the right of the side for it to slide in from the right.

Here's a demonstration of the solution I described*:

*The JQuery is for demonstration purposes only

```js
$('#navbar-collapse').click(function() {
  $('#navbar-collapse').toggleClass('changed');
})
```

```css
#navbar-collapse {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 1030;
  position: static;
}

#navbar-collapse.changed:after {
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar-collapse:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar-collapse">
  Click me!
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I will test that. How to offset the constrict the content of the page when the menu is open? My page is already responsive.

Comment: That's either going to require Javascript or significant layout changes in your website.

Comment: I updated my question with the code of my page. The first part of the code concerns the navigation bar

Comment: I would like to do something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push_opacity